# iOS 8 CNA not triggering

Tags: ios, wifi, authentication

I'm in the process of implementing a captive access point and when testing with iOS 8, I don't get shown the captive network assistant.

When I use Android and BlackBerry, they're able to detect that they're on a captive portal.  It just seems like iOS which is the odd-one-out, refusing to display any kind of prompting for the user to sign into the network.

My portal is implemented by redirecting all traffic at an IP level to a local server, which then generates a genuine HTTP redirect to our portal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS detects captive portals by attempting to access http://www.apple.com/library/test/success.html or http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html with the user agent 'wispr'.

Should this page request not return "Success", but still return a HTML page, then it shows the captive portal assistant. Make sure that you are correctly serving your captive portal page to this URL.

Comment: Actually, I just realized I had some detection code that was doing a 404.  Turns out, it worked!  Thank you :)

Comment: I wish I could auto-send your answer to every captive portal that fails on my phone @grgarside  ;-)

Comment: I'm glad I asked, this is the most direct and informed answer I've read on this subject.  Most people seem to wander around and never clearly identify what exactly the sequence is.

Answer (score 0):

> My portal is implemented by redirecting all traffic at an IP level to a local server, which then generates a genuine HTTP redirect to our portal.

Ok. But you miss another part.

Your page displayed in CNA must content the `wispr` datas.

Triggering CNA <==needs== [unreachable apple url] **+** [wispr datas in the html]

Comment: What does "must content the wispr datas" mean?  Can you elaborate?